# Roots of unity. Why is this function between $G_n$, $G_m$ bijective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups, roots-of-unity

I have been trying to prove this:

Prove that if n, m are coprime, then

$f: G_n \times G_m \rightarrow G_{n.m}$

$f (t,s)\rightarrow t.s$

is a bijective function.

I started by attempting to check if it is injective. I didn't know which way to do that, so I tried to show it using properties. 
So far, I've shown that $G_n \cap G_m=G_ {(n:m)}=G_1=1$ and that $G_n\neq G_m$, which intuitively made me think it is injective.

Then, I noticed that if I take any $t\in G_2$ and any $s\in G_3$ and plug them in the function, I get $t.s \in G_6$, which is obvious, but made me realize that I could write any $G_i$ like this, as long as it is the product of two primes, which would show it is also surjective.

How could I write this properly? I believe that my attempts are still very intuitive and would appreciate some help to prove it more rigorously.

EDIT: $G_k= \{z \in \Bbb C : z^k = 1\}$

Comment: What is $G_m$?.

Comment: Yes. It is the cyclic group of order $k$. I'm sorry about that, I should have been more specific.

Comment: Choose integers $a,b$ such that $an + bm = 1$, and use those to find the inverse of $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer and how would I use that? Would you mind explaining me a little bit? I don't see how that would work

Comment: If $z \in G_{mn}$, then $z^{km} \in G_n$ for every $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Prove that $f$ is a group homomorphism, and then find $ker(f)$.

Comment: I would like to prove it without using any linear algebra or advanced algebra, just using elementary tools.